# How to delete a folder from an Azure Fileshare using cli

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-files

I'm trying to delete the contents of a fileshare via script in order to clean it on schedule or on demand.

`az storage file delete -s $myshare -p $folderOrFileName --account-name $accountName --account-key $accountKey`

Allow me to delete files but I cannot delete a folder. Searching the web I've found several disjoined solutions like using azcopy tool or PS commands but none of them worked for me so far.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/fs/directory?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_fs_directory_delete

Comment: If that's not correct, please be clear on what "fileshare" actually means. As their are numerous technologies that this could equate too in Azure

Comment: Delete an empty folder with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/directory?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_directory_delete Use this command to list files in a directory and then delete each one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/file?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_file_list

Comment: Edit your question to clearly state what you are trying (one example) and the error message. Saying **none of them worked for me so far** is not a clear problem that can be solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `az storage directory delete` instead of `az storage file delete` to delete a folder present inside the Fileshare as file delete only deletes files and not the folders (directories).

**I tested the Scenario in my environment :**

[image]

But When I directly use the below command , I get another error as the directory is not empty , its not able to delete the entire directory.

> ```
>  az storage directory delete --share-name test --name ansumandirectory --account-name ansumanadls1234 --account-key <accountkey>
> ```
>
> [image]

So , In order to delete the Directory ,I have to delete the files present inside it as well first . So I used the below script :

```
$sharename = "test"
$foldername = "ansumandirectory"
$accountname = "ansumanadls1234"
$accountkey = "accountkey"
$source= "$sharename/$foldername"
az storage file delete-batch --source $source --account-name $accountname --account-key $accountkey 
az storage directory delete --share-name $sharename --name $foldername --account-name $accountname --account-key $accountkey
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**Note:** If Your directory is **Empty** then you can directly use the `az storage directory delete` command , it will delete the folder. But if its **not empty** then use the `az storage file delete-batch` to delete all the files with the directory delete command (as done in the above script).

Comment: Yes. That is the solution I found. I had to do a script to recursively traverse the folder tree as only empty folders can be deleted.

Comment: Glad to be of Help @Demiurge :))

Comment: When running az storage directory delete cli command, do not add "/" at the end of the folder name, otherwise you'll be getting "InvalidUri: The request URI is invalid" error. What @AnsumanBal-MT did was right.

Comment: but what if the folder contains folders, the folders will not get deleted..